# shell script - use variables from config file

Tags: command-line

My `FilePath.property` file is as below.

```
filepath1 = /var/log/Test
filepath2 = /home/Backups
```

I want to read this `FilePath.property` file inside my shell script and  use filepath1 and filepath2 in my script for deleting old logs inside the Test and Backups folders.

Answer (score 1):

The content of `Path.property` should **not** include spaces before/after the *=* sign.

```
filepath1=/var/log/Test
filepath2=/home/Backups
```

The following script will print the value of the variables:

```
source Path.property
echo $filepath1
echo $filepath2
```

You can replace the `echo` with `mv` ,`rm` commands, etc.

It works like that:

*Variable file*

```
$ cat Path.property

filepath1=/var/log/Test
filepath2=/home/Backups
```

*Script file*

```
$ cat printvar.sh

#!/bin/bash
source Path.property
echo $filepath1
echo $filepath2
```

*execution of the script*

```
$ bash printvar.sh 

/var/log/Test
/home/Backups
```

Comment: Hi Yaron..I'm not getting any output after running the below script.

Comment: source=FilePathInfo.properties

echo $filepath1

I am getting blank output it means it is not reading values inside FilePathInfo.properties.

Comment: remove the `=` from the `source` command

Comment: create `Path.property` which holds the two lines in my answer, and copy/paste the next 3 lines into `shell`

Comment: If I remove = and renamed to Path.property and getting error as source not found

Comment: I've update my answer, to include the content of `printvar.sh` and `Path.property` , and a command to run `printvar.sh` , and the result output. Please try it.

Comment: @JyothsnaChilukuri - did it work for you?

Comment: It is not all accepting if I remove = after source ...Output source not found

Comment: please run `bash`, and afterwards run `source Path.property
echo $filepath1
echo $filepath2  `

Comment: No it didn't work :(

Comment: please copy/paste your tries to https://paste.ubuntu.com/ and share the link, so I'll be able to see the problems you are facing?